# Function to find annual maximum outcome for twelve years of monthly image bands in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I have a feature collection of about 80,000 tiles, and I am trying to calculate the annual maximum drought severity index score for each tile using TerraClimate data. TerraClimate is an image collection, so I started by transforming it into a stack of images.

```
var drought_M = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE").select("pdsi")
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2012-12-31'));

//This function creates a stack of images from the image collection
function newCollectionToImage(collection){
var stack = ee.Image(collection.iterate(function(img, prev) {
return ee.Image(prev).addBands(img);
}, ee.Image(1)));
 
stack = stack.select(ee.List.sequence(1, stack.bandNames().size().subtract(1)));
return stack;
}

//This function renames the image collection bands
var drought_M_rename = drought_M.map(function(img){
var y = ee.String(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).get("year"));
return img.set("year",y).rename(y);
});

//Apply the function to create a stack of images
var droughtImageStack = newCollectionToImage(drought_M_rename);
```

How would I take this stack of images (or the image collection) and perform an image reduction that produces the annual maximum score?

Comment: This question can be closed because you have two requirements. Please, edit for having only one (by the way, the second is opinion based; another motive to be closed).

Comment: I fixed this post so that it only asked one question. Moving the second question to a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

I post here what I'd do (I discarded your code). The explanation is in the code

```
var drought_M = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE");

// add YEAR property to each image
var drought_MY = drought_M.map(function(img){
  return img.set('YEAR', img.date().get('year'))
})

// create a list of years
var years = ee.List.sequence(2000, 2012)

// iterate over years
var drought = ee.Image(years.iterate(function(year, img){
  year = ee.Number(year).toInt()
  img = ee.Image(img)
  // filter collection by YEAR
  var d = drought_MY.filter(ee.Filter.eq('YEAR', year))
                    .select('pdsi')
  // compute year's max
  var dmax = d.max().rename(year.format())
  return img.addBands(dmax)
}, ee.Image(1)))

// discard first band (coming from ee.Image(1))
var years_str = years.map(function(y){return ee.Number(y).toInt().format()})
drought = drought.select(years_str) 

// do what ever you want with the drought layer
Map.addLayer(drought, {min:-500, max:500})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4c5825498199751b60117509406c59c6